# Is it necessary to change <h2>'s to <h1>'s when the main <h1> is removed?

Tags: html, css

I'm following the CodeSchool foundation course now with HTML. Its saying its 'not OK' to not have a `<h2>` heading as the top one:

> we removed the h1 tag and replaced it with an img tag. That's fine, but it also means that our highest level heading right now is an h2 tag, which isn't OK.

Is this going to affect the final product or is it just a design thing?

Comment: keep the h1 with text matching teh title, remove its visibility (one way or another).

Comment: What bothers me the most is replacing an `<h1>` with an image. Was the h1 just decorative all along? Or the other way, if the h1 is being replaced with an image that is a picture of fancy text, ***don't do it***... you are losing semantic meaning.

Comment: Or, here's a novel idea, place the image inside of the h1 and make sure the image has alternate text. You know, if you want to do it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing will break if there is a h2 and no h1. However, the way computers read websites, is by parsing the HTML. The only way the computer knows that something is a top-level header (h1) is by finding the h1 tag.

The most common reason I can think of at the moment, as to why you want h1 insted of h2, is how search engines index your website. Using a h1, means that the text within the tag is highly relevant to your website, while h2 is not as important (but still more important than h3 for example).

So it's not about what works and don't works, but it's about what things should be. Writing a website, following all the "rules" of HTML, will make it easily parsable by crawlers (programs that parse websites and gather information).

Another, important, reason why your html should be well-structured is for blind people. They use programs that read out text from websites to "read" the website. Having bad semantic/bad structured html might make these programs useless.

Edit:
Sorry, as mentioned, document outline would break, but the website would still be rendered, which is what I was referring to.

Comment: "Nothing will break if there is a h2 and no h1. " The HTML Document Outline will break. Also, SEO and heading levels are not related - - at all.

Comment: But if I am blind, I really don't care about the page being rendered. I need to be able to consume the page's content and I won't be able to do that with a broken outline.

Answer (score 0):

The heading elements are used to provide semantic meaning to your content (as most HTML elements do). In addition, people who use assistive technologies, such as screen readers, rely on certain HTML elements to provide information as to how to navigate a page. The heading elements (h1...h6) help to create the page's Document Outline, for which there is a defined specification.

If you were to start with an h2, the outline would be broken.

Just as it makes no sense to stat a report on section 2, you should not start a web page there for the same reason.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but the outline doesn't break if you start with an H2. As stated [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML_sections_and_outlines#Defining_headings) _"Any rank can be used as the heading of an explicitly-defined section, although this practice is not recommended."_ - this includes the `<body>`

Comment: Yes, but you must fully read that spec. as I said there are many nuances. If you are not using the HTML5 sectioning elements (article, section, nav, aside), that passage does not apply. Additionally, the conventional wisdom when you ARE using those elements is to start with h1. But, for reasons that are too complex to go into here, those elements should be avoided. Read: "The Truth About HTML5" for a great explanation.

Comment: The body is a sectioning element - and it does apply - _"The basic rule is simple: the first HTML heading element (one of <h1>, <h2>, <h3>, <h4>, <h5>, <h6>) defines the heading of the current section."_

Comment: body is an implied section root, which has different rules than explicit sections.

Comment: I'm not arguing about this. [As stated here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML_sections_and_outlines#Defining_sections) _"All content lying inside the <body> element is part of a section. Sections in HTML5 can be nested. Beside the main section, defined by the <body> element, section limits are defined either explicitly or implicitly."_

Comment: Read the ENTIRE spec. There are exceptions and catch-22's.

Comment: As I have provided links and descriptions as to why you are mistaken, please enlighten us with proof. The [same article on the authoritative MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML_sections_and_outlines#Implicit_sectioning) goes on to define implicit sectioning as _"The heading elements (<h1> to <h6>) define a new, implicit, section when they aren't the first heading of their parent, explicit, sections. The way this implicit section is positioned in the outline is **defined by its relative rank with the previous heading** in their parent section."_

Comment: @RyanWheale We can go round and round all day on this, but I have read the entire spec and worked with this code first hand. You are providing snippets without context. Your last comment is EXACTLY what I just posted to you. Do you know what it means?  What would <section><h2>something</h2><h2>something else</h2><h1>something else again</h1></section> do? What about that same code, but without the <section> element?  Now, ask yourself how to consistently style your heading elements throughout your page, when some h2's are really h1's and not all h1's are h1's.

Comment: @RyanWheale Again, you can cherry pick excerpts from the spec. but until you've read the whole thing and built actual code that follows it, you really won't have a true understanding of its meaning. HINT: The best advice is to not use the HTML5 sectioning elements at all and use logically numbered headings, as you would in a report.

Comment: @RyanWheale And, you know, it just dawned on me that the points we are discussing don't change the fact that headings are not associated with SEO. What we are discussing is the creation of a viable document outline, which affects assistive technology users. And, you've even quoted the spec. saying that using ranks other than h1 as the first heading in a section is not recommended.

Comment: @RyanWheale Here's a good page that discusses the outline and since you like snippets, please note the section (pardon the punn) call "Practical Advice" where the spec specifically strongly recommends to use appropriate heading rank and not to rely on the new HTML5 sectioning elements (and the rules about how headings work within them) working properly in user agents.  https://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2013/10/html5-document-outline/

Comment: @RyanWheale You asked for more sources. Have a look at this well-known file the exposes how ludicrous it is to follow the sectioning elements and headings paradigm when CSS comes into play:  https://github.com/cboone/hypsometric-css/blob/master/html5/html5-defaults.css#l426  You have to understand how all this stuff comes together in a real-world application to know that headings should be used in sequence and without the HTML5 sectioning elements.  Oh, and feel free to load up your pages with all h1's so you get to the top of the results (wouldn't we all do that if headings affected SEO?)

Comment: The links you provided have nothing to do with the conversation we are having. Your answer says _"If you were to start with an h2, the outline would be broken."_ - and I said that is wrong and provided sources which support that. All you have done is ramble about... not much of anything substantive and seem overly eager to make claims to both me and others on this page without any proof.

Answer (score 0):

**SEO**

Search Engine Optimalization! If a person searches for, say, "Rubik's Cubes", a search engine will look through their data to see which sites have the string "Rubik's Cubes" (or some substring or related words) on their site.

Now, if your site has the string "Rubik's Cubes" in an `<h1>` tag, the search engine will understand that this is the entire point of your page, and rank it higher, because it's the title of the entire page!

Meanwhile, if you have it in an `<h2>` it's probably just some part of the page, and that's fine too, but not AS good.

So while structurally, it makes no difference, think of SEO when you choose which header you use. If you're picking them just based on size, that's a bad idea. Just style them bigger/smaller instead!

Comment: SEO and headings are not related --- at all.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Wow, I didn't know that. Where can I learn more about this?

Comment: There is a lot of information about SEO out there and MUCH of it is myth. The document outline can be read about at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML_sections_and_outlines but, there are many nuances to creating them properly.

Comment: @Alec If your pages were ranked higher because keywords were inside of h1 elements, everyone would just put all their text in h1 elements and use CSS to style them as normal. That's not how search engines rank you.

Comment: @ScottMarcus proper usage of headings surely affects SEO ranking. how can you say this? Run an A/B test and put 10 `h1` tags in one document and see how it ranks

Comment: MANY tests have been done, but the ranking is not affected by h1. What proper use of h1 can do is make the page more readable and therefore increase traffic or decrease bounce rates of page consumption. If h1 was taken into account for rankings (as used to be the case many years ago, along with meta keywords) everyone would just put everything in an h1 and use CSS to style the text back to normal. Headings and SEO are a myth.

Comment: @ScottMarcus - You may well be right. It might be a myth. But it's a well documented myth in that case, so if you wouldn't mind giving me some reading material?

Comment: It's hard to find material that explains how something is NOT related to something else and there are MANY SEO myths out there. You can do your own research, but I am right (I"ve been teaching this stuff for 20 years by the way) and am just trying to explain why.

Comment: Well, if you have no sources, where did YOU learn it? And don't say "I tested it".

Comment: I just provided an excellent reference called "The Truth About HTML5" by Luke Stevens. But, I learned it from reading and understanding the spec. that I have provided. It's very complex, but for example, let's say you go ahead and start a section with an h3 (after all the spec. says that you can do this). What happens when you wish to create a new section at a higher level - - you need to put an h2 in that section. But, wait!  An h2 following an h3? And, what about two h3's in a row?

Comment: Oh, by the way in an explicit section, the first heading is used as the title for that section, it doesn't create a new section within that section, but the second an subsequent headings do!  The BEST explanation for this is the document outline spec. But, you can just take snippets out of it, you must understand it in its entirety.

Comment: That reference neither confirms nor denies any of our points. It doesn't touch on the subject of SEO at all. Don't tell me you have this amazing gift of "understanding" things that aren't there.

Comment: @Alec The spec says nothing about SEO because SEO is not related to it. You seem to want to be combative about an idea that you thought was true, but flat out isn't. You want me to provide you proof, but you can just google "headings and SEO" to find ample material. Here's a question for you... With <meta name=keywords content="..."> improve my rankings?  If so, can you prove it by supplying a reference source?  If not, can you explain why?  This is EXACTLY the same scenario with headings.

Comment: Well, with all these other articles claiming they ARE related, it's kinda hard to believe that it isn't, just because you found a link where it isn't mentioned at all.

Comment: @Alec I'm talking about the actual specification for document outlines, not just some link.  Hey man, believe what you want, but perhaps you could try answering the questions I asked in my last post?

Comment: @Alec there was a time where all the articles and studies both claimed and _proved_ the earth was flat, and it was kinda hard to believe that it wasn't. Only a few crackpots said the earth was a sphere.

Comment: @StephenP - Clever. But then Magellan sailed around the world and **proved it**.